# How to distinguish between a variable and a control factor in Anova design

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, variable

Suppose I have an experiment in which participants are presented with different types of colored objects, hence 4 variables are introduced (i.e., blue, red, white, black).

Participants are then requested to grasp the object as soon as it is presented. That is, I might suppose that grasping a blue object requires more time rather than grasping a white object.

To avoid habituation from the participants I also have an acoustic cue (high-pitched vs. low-pitched noise). If the sound is high-pitched the participant have to grasp the object at the bottom, if it is low-pitched they have to grasp it at the top. However, I have no specific hypothesis on this difference, I am only using this to avoid that participants get used to the task.

If I want to analyze the data, should I analyze it as a 4(color)x2(top/bottom)? Or should I only take into account exclusively the color variable?

This is not an actual experiment, this is just an example.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is part of your design, the top/bottom factor should definitely be in the model, regardless of significance.